# Evaluating the sum of a series to a power and finding the limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I wish to find the limit of the following series:
$$
\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n := (1 + 2^2 + ... + n^n)^{(\frac{1}{n^2})}
$$

I'm currently doing basic real analysis although I've never come across a series to a power before - I'm fairly sure $a_n$ tends to 1 yet I have no idea how to prove it.

I don't need the answer - just a pointer in the right direction would be nice

Thanks.

Comment: Here it is $$\rightarrow$$

Comment: Squeeze! $1+2^2+\cdots+n^n \le n\cdot n^n = n^{n+1}$.